# Making a half-elliptical path in MATLAB from three input points through 3D space, to be fed into Visual Studio and ultimately a robotic arm

Tags: matlab, math, geometry, robotics, coordinate-systems

First, a little bit about my set up: I have a robotic arm into which points and movement patterns can be programmed into. The goal is to get it to move in certain ways based on the inputs that we put into it.

On the same table as the robotic arm is another arm that moves under human power and can sense where it is in space. The two arms share a coordinate system already, but I am having trouble with a particular calcuation that is giving me a headache.

The current goal is specifically to take three points with the sensing arm and then translate that into a half-ellipse arc that travels through the three of them. This arc should start at the first point, reach apex at the second, and finish on the third, traveling through all three dimensions to do so if necessary. The three points feed through Visual Studio, then are put into MATLAB and turned into an array of 99 xyz coordinates.

We have every step working except for the MATLAB function. The points are nowhere near the actual coordinates, though the relationship between them seems okay. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code?

Here is what we have so far:

```
function P = getEllipticalPath(h0,hl,hr)
%define center of ellipse
center = (hl+hr)/2;

%want everything centered at (0,0,0)
h0 = h0 - center;
hl = hl - center;
hr = hr - center;

%xz plane direction between h0 and center
d = [h0(1),0,0]/49;

%now get the major/minor axis of the ellipse
%minor axis(along z axis)
a = h0(3);
b = hr(2);%arbitrary with hr

%set increment of orbit
incr = (pi)/99;

%by symmetry, only need to compute first half of orbit
%allocation
Pf = zeros(99,3);
for i=1:99
    if(i < 50)
       newpt = [0, b*cos(i*incr), a*sin(i*incr)] + (i*d);
    else 
        newpt = [0, b*cos(i*incr), a*sin(i*incr)] + (99 - i)*d;
    end 

    Pf(i,:) = [newpt(1), newpt(2), newpt(3)];
end
P = addOffset(Pf,-h0);

end

%simply adds a fixed translational offset to the given list of vectors
%(n*3 matrix). Assumes a matrix that is longer than 3.

function P = addOffset(points,offset)
newpoints = zeros(length(points),3);
for i=1:length(points);

    newpoints(i,:) = points(i,:) + offset;
end
P = newpoints;
end
```

EDIT: Forgot input-output information; here is an example:

Input:

```
>> h0 = [-10.06   14.17   0.53 ]

h0 =

  -10.0600   14.1700    0.5300

>> hl = [-45.49   7.87   1.07 ]

hl =

  -45.4900    7.8700    1.0700

>> hr = [-4.52   -20.73   1.02 ]

hr =

   -4.5200  -20.7300    1.0200

>> P = getEllipticalPath(h0,hl,hr)
```

Output:

[image: This is very different from ecpectations. We would expect it to start on hl, move in increments through h0 and end on hr, but instead we get this.]

Comment: Can you give us some sample input, expected and actual output, please?

Comment: 99/2 is 49.5 not 49, if that's a mistake (not sure yet)

Comment: Patashu: that is purposeful, I believe; it actually return 98 points, and the last one is used for some kind of positioning variable in the robot.

Comment: So far I've figured out that the first point in Pf and the last point in Pf aren't near hl and hr - both before and after adding offsets.

Comment: Added sample input and resulting output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you complicated things for yourself with all the offsetting and stuff. I think what you want to do is this:

- Get the center vertex C of the ellipse as (hl+hr)/2
- Get the major axis vector B as (center-hl)
- Get the minor axis vector A as (h0-center)
- Get the angular delta float INCR as (pi)/99
- Now you can calculate each vertex in PF from i = 1 to 99 as `center *(vertex)* + B*cos(i*incr) *(vector)* + A*sin(i*incr) *(vector)*`

Basically you're starting at the center, moving towards hr or hl according to the cos of the angle, and moving towards h0 as the sin of the angle, using those vectors to control how far and in which direction you move.